# Why a shared library found in obj/local/armeabi is bigger in size than its version in libs/armeabi?

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am building a native part of an application using ndk in eclipse in a bare project.
I later copy the resulting libmylib.so in libs/armeabi/ to another project where it is used.

I noticed that the library size in obj/local/armeabi/ , which is the local build output path,
is about 4x bigger than the library in libs/armeabi/ .

to be more precise:

libmylib.so is about 4mb in size in obj/local/armeabi/ and it depends on a 6mb static lib and on stl-port and
it all boils down to 1.5mb in libs/armeabi/ ... I am worried.

Is it safe for me to just copy the libs/ folder to the other project? can I trust that
my code run as expected?

In a different place and on a different platform the code runs perfectly well.

Comment: Is it possible that this is just a difference between a library that contains symbols and one that is stripped?

Comment: You seem to be right @Michael , I used nm to list all symbols and indeed the smaller version contained none , while the obj version contained a ton.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, you should post your answer as **answer**

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer 
It was, as MichaeBurr suggested in his comment,due to the fact that the 'official'
version of the lib does not contain any symbols, while the local build version containes all symbols.

One can use nm to list symbols in library to validate that.